# Error al tratar de obtener la propiedad de no-objeto

Tags: laravel-5

Mi programa funcionaba correctamente y de un momento a otro empezó a sacar este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

verificando mi código no entiendo porque dice que estoy tratando de acceder a la propiedad de un no-objeto cuando estoy guardando el resultado de la consulta en la variable $pre para acceder a los datos. Adicional me dice que $pre es nulo. Alguien me puede ayudar a corregir este error?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adiciono mi archivo php para verificar lo que estoy llamando en cada uno de los metodos.

reporte_mantenimiento_pre.php

```
<?php

namespace GeomedicosApp;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Reporte_mantenimiento_pre extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'reporte_mantenimiento_pre';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['numeroReporte', 'fecha', 'tipoActividad',
        'equipo_id', 'biomedico_id'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /*Tiene uno */

    public function equipo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('GeomedicosApp\Equipo', 'equipo_id')->withTrashed();
    }

    public function biomedico()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('GeomedicosApp\Biomedico', 'biomedico_id')->withTrashed();
    }

    public function scopeSearch($query, $search)
    {
        if (trim($search) != "") {//Lafunción trim elimina los espacios, para que aunque
            //no se escriba nada en el buscador o se de espacio, cargue los resultados
            $query->where('numeroReporte', "like", "%$search%");
        }

    }

    public function scopeCliente($query, $cliente)
    {
        if (trim($cliente) != "") {//Lafunción trim elimina los espacios, para que aunque
            //no se escriba nada en el buscador o se de espacio, cargue los resultados
            $query->select('reporte_mantenimiento_pre.*')
                ->join('equipos as eq', 'reporte_mantenimiento_pre.equipo_id', '=', 'eq.id')
                ->join('clientes as cl', 'eq.cliente_id', '=', 'cl.id')
                ->where('cl.id', $cliente)
                ->get();
        }
    }

    public function scopeBiomedico($query, $cliente)
    {
        if (trim($cliente) != "") {//Lafunción trim elimina los espacios, para que aunque
            //no se escriba nada en el buscador o se de espacio, cargue los resultados
            $query->where('biomedico_id', $cliente);
        }
    }

    public function scopeFecha($query, $fecha)
    {
        if (trim($fecha) != "") {//Lafunción trim elimina los espacios, para que aunque
            //no se escriba nada en el buscador o se de espacio, cargue los resultados
            $query->where('fecha', $fecha);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No sabemos lo que es Reporte_mantenimiento_pre, no se como podemos ayudarte como no sea ir suponiendo cosas

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te está pasando es que en la línea:

```
$pre = Reporte_mantenimiento_pre::find($request['numeroReporte']);
```

Te estará devolviendo null, ya que la función find te devuelve null cuando no encuentra el id en la tabla del modelo.
Tendrás que capturarlo con un try catch o poner un if para tenerlo en cuenta que puede que no encuentre el numeroReporte en la tabla